# iOS app crashes immediately if not running from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

When run app through Xcode everything works fine. As soon as I disconnect device and try to launch app by tapping on icon it flashes screen and disappear immediately. One of the answers for similar behavior answers that you might don't have Apple dev account, but I do

Comment: With **zero** code to go by, any help you receive is going to be a "shot in the dark"  --   I recommend disabling features of your app one-by-one until it will run ..  Then figure out what feature is causing the problem, and go from there ...

Answer (score 2):

Check device logs. Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators. Select device from list and click 'View Device Logs'

Comment: This answer should be instead made as a comment.

Comment: I didn't have enough stackoverflow reputation to add comment.

Comment: I don't think this will work as the crash happens when not ran on Xcode.